# Active Directory Authentication in Linux Docker Container in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: docker, active-directory, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0, windows-authentication

I am trying to use Active Directory to authenticate users in a .NET Core 2.0 Web API hosted in a Linux Docker container. When I run the app outside of Docker in Visual Studio 2017, I am able to use System.DirectoryServices (through Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility) to perform this, but this is unsupported when it is running in the Linux Docker container.

How can I implement AD authentication from within the Linux container?

My System:
- Windows 10 Pro
- Visual Studio 2017 (15.8.2)
- .NET Core 2.0

Thanks!

Kevin

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem